# MIDL changes case of identifier when compiling IDL file

Tags: midl

I've got a snippet of IDL that looks like this:

```
[ object, uuid(...), pointer_default(unique) ]
interface IVirtualMachine { /* ... */ }

[ object, uuid(...), pointer_default(unique) ]
interface IVirtualServer : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT FindVirtualMachine(
        [in] BSTR configurationName,
        [out,retval] IVirtualMachine **virtualMachine);
};

[ uuid(...), version(1.0) ]
library VirtualServerLib
{
    [ uuid(...) ]
    coclass VirtualServer
    {
        [default] interface IVirtualServer;
    };

    [ uuid(...) ]
    coclass VirtualMachine
    {
        [default] interface IVirtualMachine;
    };
};
```

...when I compile it with MIDL and then look in the generated type library, `VirtualMachine` (upper-case V) has been turned into `virtualMachine` (lower-case V).

If I call my coclass `XirtualMachine`, for example, it's all good.

What the hell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a terrible bug/feature of MIDL.  It doesn't allow the same identifier to appear with different casing, so it replaces all subsequent instances of a word with the casing from the first time it was seen.

See the [KB220137](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/220137)

Answer (score 0):

OK. Worked it out. It was this line here:

```
[out,retval] IVirtualMachine **virtualMachine);
```

If I change it to:

```
[out,retval] IVirtualMachine **ppVirtualMachine);
```

...then it works fine. Something screwy in MIDL, I guess. Maybe it's trying to do VB-like case correction.