# Cause for non-determenistic behaviour of `tlbexp.exe`?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compilation

I am using `tlbexp.exe` to generate a type library from a C# project. The project contains 2 files - let's call them F1 and F2 - with COM interface declarations. F1 and F2 contain identifiers that differ in case only (F1 has property "Foo", F2 has variable name "foo"). Because of this I am affected by the "MIDL changes the case of identifier in generated type library" problem (cf. [this MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/220137), or also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278166/midl-changes-case-of-identifier-when-compiling-idl-file)).

Now the interesting thing is that `tlbexp.exe` sometimes produces a type library that is correct, and sometimes it produces a type library that is incorrect:

- If I compile the project on branch A on my dev machine, the type library is correct. This means that `tlbexp.exe` has seen the files in order F1, F2
- If I compile the project on branch B, on the same machine, the type library is incorrect. `tlbexp.exe` has seen the files in order F2, F1.
- If I compile the project on the build server, the type library is correct for both branches!
- If I compile the project on a fellow developer's machine, I get the same results as on my own dev machine (i.e. OK for branch A, fail for branch B)
- The projects on branch A and B are identical - I have checked this by recursive-comparing all files/folders.

Now my question is: What is causing this weird and non-determenistic behaviour of `tlbexp.exe`? Note that I am asking this question out of curiosity - I have already solved my type library problem by merging the two files F1 and F2 into one.

In case it's important: I have Visual Studio 2010 SP1, and my projects are set up to use .NET 4.

---

The answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130280/tlbexp-exe-changes-method-names-case) claims that it's the compilation order that is non-deterministic. I find this hard to believe - given the exactly same input and the exactly same build tools, non-deterministic behaviour would mean that the build tool makers must have equipped their build tools with a "random generator" that makes sure that compilation order is not the same every time. Isn't that pretty unlikely? Or am I overlooking something?

Having said all that, I have tried to verify the compilation order by increasing the MSBuild build output from "minimal" to "diagnostic". Looking at the build output, I see a line like this for a build that fails:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe [...] F1.cs F2.cs [...]
```

As you can see, the files appear in the correct order F1, F2. I compared this with a successful build, and the `csc.exe` command line is exactly the same. So it really seems as if compilation order is not the problem.

---

EDIT: I understand that `tlbexp.exe` may not be the root cause, so the title of this question may be somewhat inadequate.

Comment: I've run into this problem before and from my experience your best off renaming one of the identifiers.  It sucks but it will save you a *lot* of pain here.

Comment: Compiler multi-threading could cause non-deterministic build behavior without anyone throwing in a "random generator."  I cannot say whether that is the case here, but it is certainly possible.